# I don't know how to use in this case the method of an object in other object

Tags: javascript, object, methods

this is my first question here. So i'll make it simple.

I don´t know how to use the method "htmlobj1.paint" in htmlobj2.
 I tried using call, but i think i did it wrong. So here's the code:

PD: htmlobj1.paint works. I would be very thankful for any kind of advice you want to give me to continue this code. Thank you!

```
<body>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Adress</th>
        <th>Mutant</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>22</td>
        <td>???</td>
        <td>Berkley St 304</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>??</td>
        <td>???</td>
        <td>Conecticut Av 904</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <h1>Text</h1><br>
    <h1>Text</h1><br>
    <h1>Text</h1><br>
    <h1>Text</h1><br>
    <h1>Text</h1><br>
    <h1>Text</h1><br>
</body>
var htmlobj2 = {
    e: document.getElementsByTagName("h1"),
}
var htmlobj1 = {
    e: document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    paint: function(e){
        e = this.e;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                e[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                e[i].style.color = "white";
            }
            else {
                e[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"
                e[i].style.color = "white";
            }
        }       
    }
}
var arr = [].slice.call(htmlobj1.e);
var arr2 = [].slice.call(htmlobj2.e);
var myFunction = htmlobj1.paint();
```

Comment: `htmlobj2.paint = htmlobj1.paint;` Putting this after the creation of `htmlobj1` will assign that function so that it's usable, but IMO, this isn't the best design. Seems like you want a "class" of sorts.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any code that tries to use `htmlobj2` with `htmlobj1.paint`. Can you provide more clarification on what you're trying to do (even if it's incorrect code)?

Comment: ...you'll also need to do the slicing of the HTMLCollection inside the function so that it is operating on the right collection.

Answer (score 1):

An example of idiomatic code would be to use a constructor function *(or the newer `class` syntax)* to create instances of objects that share behavior via methods.

```
function MyCtor(tagName) {
  this.e = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
}
MyCtor.prototype.paint = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            this.e[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
        } else {
            this.e[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"
        }
        this.e[i].style.color = "white";
    }       
}
var htmlobj1 = new MyCtor("td")
var htmlobj2 = new MyCtor("h1")

htmlobj1.paint()
htmlobj2.paint()
```

Now you have a constructor function that produces object that inherit the `paint` method. This method can use `this` to operate on the collection that was fetched when the constructor was invoked.

---

Using modern features, you can rewrite the code like this:

```
class MyCtor {
    constructor(tagName) {
      this.e = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tagName))
    }
    paint(){
        for (var [i, el] of this.e.entries()) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = i % 2 == 0 ? "red" : "green"
            el.style.color = "white";
        }       
    }
}
var htmlobj1 = new MyCtor("td")
var htmlobj2 = new MyCtor("h1")

htmlobj1.paint()
htmlobj2.paint()
```

Note that I used `var` instead of `const` in the `for-of` statement. The `const` declaration would be better, but doesn't work just yet in that position in Firefox.

Also note that I shortened things a bit when setting the `backgroundColor` by using the *conditional operator*. This could be done in the first example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all together that was said in the comments:

```
function createCustomObj(tag){
   return {
     elems: [...document.getElementsByTagName(tag)], //convert to array, the ES6 way...
     paint: function(){
         this.elems.forEach((elem,index)=>{
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
              elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
              elem.style.color = "white";
            }else {
               elem.style.backgroundColor = "green"
               elem.style.color = "white";
            }
         });       
     }
};
}
```

Use like this:

```
htmlobj1=createCustomObj("h1");
htmlobj1.paint();
```

Comment: If you just use `Array.from` instead of the spread element syntax, you don't need the explaining comment…